# How to cleanly merge branch containing revert (branch containing revert sees revert as new changes)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I have a branch containing a revert that I would like to move to master.

However, the revert seems to be seen as new changes and applies them to master when it is merged. This is overwriting a lot of things in master that should be untouched.

I would like to merge to master as if the **reverted** commit never happened. Is there a way to do this?

If not, what do I need to do to the branch containing the revert in order to get it to a state where I can merge without overwriting the revert contents?

Answer (score 1):

On your branch, simply revert the revert commit, i.e.

```
git revert <sha of revert commit>
```

This will "undo the undoing," if you will.

Comment: While this does "undo the undoing" that would make it as if the **revert** commit never happened rather than the **reverted** commit. In this case I believe our solution was to create a new branch and cherry pick the correct commits over. I'm still curious if there is a command to do this though.